# Enable promiscuous mode on Libvirt vif

Tags: iptables, xen, libvirt

Does anyone know how to enable promiscuous mode on a libvirt vif? 
I have a bridge with 3 vifs connected to it. I need one of these vifs to be able to sniff all the traffic flowing through the bridge.
The interface has the following iptable rules:
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif32.2 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif32.2 --physdev-is-bridged

How could I change this so the vif can get all packets regardless of the MAC address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I was looking for but this worked for me:

```
brctl setageing bridgename 0
```